# Meta-annotation with @Pattern not working in spring

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

annotation as follows:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$")
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyTestAnnotation {

}
```

When I annotate a field with @MyTestAnnotion, even if the field does not contain all numbers, the call goes through without any error.

The following part has been resolved by the answer given below. The main issue still exists.
I tried adding :

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$")
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface MyTestAnnotation {

}
```

On my @MyTestAnnotation, it wont let me enter a message attribute but when I run the code it gives the error saying message attribute not specified.

If I put the @Pattern annotation directly on the field it behaves as expected.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring just how JSR-303 (Bean Validation) works.

Answer (score 8):

Your annotation is wrong. See [section 3.1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintdefinition-properties) of the bean validation spec for the minimal properties of a constraint and [section 3.3](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition) on how to do proper composition.

Your annotation is missing the `message`, `groups` and `payload` properties.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$")
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface MyTestAnnotation {

    String message() default "{com.acme.constraint.MyConstraint.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Without these properties your annotation isn't considered to be a constraint.

Comment: I added this and am no longer getting the "message parameter missing" exception but the @Pattern still won't kick in. It still accepts the field with value "abc" even though the regex expects all numbers –